# Usage of var keyword in the core

Tags: php, core, user-access

I've noticed many of the classes throughout the core declare member variables with the `var` keyword YET in the comments (written above the variable) it's declared as being a private access. [The PHP docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) state:

> The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still
>   supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public
>   keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT
>   warning.

I.e. It's public. So which is it? (Does anybody still use PHP 4?)

In my case I'm extending the `WP_Error` class and would like access to the `errors` variable. (I want to `array_merge` rather than call on `add` for each error). [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) simply mentions it as being a "Property" of the class, which leads me to think it is intended to be public. So, either the inline comments are wrong or the Codex is, which?

I know that it being declared `var` makes it public but how am I to know if, in the next release, it isn't going to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally WordPress backward compatibility is **very** strong, (sometimes too much strong IMHO).

So it's close to impossible that a public property (properties declared with `var` are `public` at any effects) become private in a future release. However, as you noticed, the variable is marked as *private* in class doc block, this mean that developers *should not* use that variable directly, but via public methods, so possibility that in a future versions (when core developers decide to remove any PHP 4 code) property will be declared as *private* increase.

What I can suggest is ignore recomendation and access that variable direclty, or better, use a getter like

```
function get_errors() {
  return $this->errors;
}
```

and if in future versions the variable became `private` and no public getter is added, try to adjust your code, or maybe submit a patch to core that add the getter and/or declare the variable as `protected`.

Comment: Also being mentioned in the codex just adds to the confusion. In this case I'm thinking the original coder intended it to be private but since V2.1 things have changed and that file just hasn't had its comments updated. Also, I think it being changed to `private` is very slim, possibly `protected` in which case I'm still safe. But this is just one of possibly hundreds of cases.

Comment: I understand your point, but when working with core files, specially when not uptated since a long time, is impossible to write a function that will work *for sure* in future versions. Only thing you can do is write your code as flexible as you can, in a way that is easily adaptable to possible changes. Using the getter is a little step in that direction.

Comment: I'd really like to see a branch of the core that is completely rewritten to exclude global variables, use classes throughout and drop all the backward compatibility. And I'd like that branch to be written with CMS in mind. WP has become far too bloated.

Comment: @Waldermort you'd like to see something that is not WordPress ;)

Comment: Lol, true, but it'd still be a WordPress port. How about CMSPress or ContentPress...